# How to send test result to testrail if test failed on any step?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, user-interface, testrail

Using our company framework to send testrail results
It was easy with api tests
Example

```
rail = TestRail(project_id=23, debug=True, debug_run_id=484)

    def test_payment_system(self):
        payload = {"system": "qiwi"}
        response = requests.get(urlpayment, params=payload, headers=self.beareradmin)
        responseArray = response.json()
        system = responseArray['items'][0]['payment_system']
        if 'qiwi' in system:
            rail.send_passed(21893, 'passed')
        else:
            rail.send_failed(21893, '')
```

So i have verifying that by string 'qiwi' in responseArray.
And sending status to test rail `rail.send_passed(self, case_id,comment)`

But i have a problem in UI tests.

Example

```
 def test_loginok(self):
            self.browser.get(login)
            self.getXpathElement(login_mail).click()
            self.getXpathElement(login_mail).send_keys('auto@test.com')
            self.getXpathElement(login_password).click()
            self.getXpathElement(login_password).send_keys('qwerty')
            self.getClassElement(button_sign_in).click()
            self.getXpathElement("//li[contains(@class,'active')]//a")
```

How to verify that test is passed or failed?
In my case test is passed if `self.getXpathElement("//li[contains(@class,'active')]//a")` is present on the page.

**I dont know how to create "if/else with rail.send_passed/failed" or another case to send result**

And if test will failed on step #2 `self.getXpathElement(login_mail).click()` i wont send anything to testrail.

Tried

````
def check(self, xpath):
try:
    self.find elem by xpath(xpath)
   except NoSuchElementException
 return False
Returne True```
As ```r = check("//li[contains(@class,'active')]//a")
 if r == True:
 rail.send_passed(case_id, 'comment')
else:
rail.send_failed(case_id, 'comment')
````

But i cant use this method to all my steps in case.